# How to read records from a text file?

Tags: java

```
I tried this:
public static void ReadRecord()
    {
        String line = null;
        try
        {
        FileReader fr = new FileReader("input.txt");
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);

        line = br.readLine();
         while(line != null)
         {
                System.out.println(line);
         }  

        br.close();
        fr.close();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

It non stop and repeatedly reads only one record that i had inputtd and wrote into the file earlier...How do i read records and use tokenization in reading records?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reading and Writing to a .txt file in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15801528/reading-and-writing-to-a-txt-file-in-java)

Comment: You are only reading a single line from the file, and then doing `while(line != null)`. `line` will never change in the scope of your while loop so it will loop forever. You need to read the file in a loop if you want to keep reading lines from it.

Comment: I'm struggling with file handling.
Could anyone guide me about tokenisation?

Answer (score 3):

You have to read the lines in the file repeatedly in the loop using `br.readLine()`. `br.readLine()` reads only one line at time.

do something like this:

```
while((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    
     System.out.println(line);
}
```

Check this link also if you have some problems. http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-file-from-java-bufferedreader-example/

### Tokenization

If you want to split your string into tokens you can use the `StringTokenizer` class or can use the `String.split()` method.

#### StringTokenizer Class

```
StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(line);
while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {
     System.out.println(st.nextToken());
}
```

`st.hasMoreTokens()`  - will check whether any more tokens are present. 
`st.nextToken()`      - will get the next token

#### String.split()

```
String[] result = line.split("\\s"); // split line into tokens
for (int x=0; x<result.length; x++) {
     System.out.println(result[x]);
}
```

`line.split("\\s")` - will split `line` with `space` as the delimiter. It returns a String array.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
     while((line = br.readLine()) != null)
     {
            System.out.println(line);
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This :

```
     BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("input.txt"));
     while((line=br.readline())!=null)
     System.out.println(line);
```

Answer (score 0):

For a text file called access.txt locate for example on your X drive, this should work.

```
public static void readRecordFromTextFile throws FileNotFoundException

{
    try {
        File file = new File("X:\\access.txt");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(file);
        sc.useDelimiter(",|\r\n");
        System.out.println(sc.next());
        while (sc.hasNext()) {
            System.out.println(sc.next());
        }

        sc.close();// closing the scanner stream
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

        System.out.println("Enter existing file name");

        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```